# Converting an audio file to char and sending to another device to listen to

Tags: objective-c

I'm new in objective-C and I'm not getting to converting an audio file to char exactly I need. It is ignoring a sequence of zeros (0) and it's deforming the data structure.
My code is so:

```
-(NSString *) dataToHex:(NSData*) data {
    const unsigned char *dbytes = (unsigned char*)[data bytes];
    NSMutableString *hexStr =
    [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[data length]/**2*/];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [data length]; i++) {
        [hexStr appendFormat:@"%x", dbytes[i]];
    }
    return [NSString stringWithString: hexStr];
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly the issue is with your format `%x` - this produces a hexadecimal text representation with *sufficient* digits to represent the value and *without* any leading zeroes.

For example the value 32 will produce the text `20`, while the value 12 produces `c` - only one character long.

If you wish to convert to hex representation and then back again each of your byte values needs to produce the same number of characters - as otherwise you can't know where the boundaries are between each byte's representation.

To do this you can use the format `%02x`, which means always produce two characters padding with zeroes as required. For example with this format 12 will produce `0c`.

HTH

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. Do you have any idea how I can do this? Preserve the spaces in my hexadecimal?

Comment: @WilliamPenna - I've edited the answer slightly for clarity, does that help?

Comment: Thank you again @CRD. Now, it's converting.

Comment: Now the problem is other. After I convert my audio file to char *, the archive is exactly equal the nsdata I've converted. But it doesn't reproduce the audio. But the nsdata it reproduces normally.

Comment: That is a different problem. You can ask a new question, showing how you are playing the audio, what you do with the hex string, what doesn't work, what you've tried to solve the problem, etc.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.